# storing background images in userdefaults

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I need to be able to set the background image for this button. I need to store this so after the app closes the background image is the same.

```
eventsFirstButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "events")!)
```

Comment: Where are you setting this? If you put this into viewDidLoad you dont have to save to UserDefaults. Also userdefaults is not the place to save large pieces of data.

Comment: if a user has finished the test and got correct answers set the background color to green but if they have not finished the test set the color to red so if the color is green it would stay green to show they have finished the test and can try another one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just save the state:

Correct answer:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "TestAnswer1")
//If the answer is incorrect set to false
```

On load:

```
 if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "TestAnswer1") {
      view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
      // or any other logic
 } else {
      view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
      // or any other logic
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

It's better to save it as `base64string`, you don't want to store large value to UserDefaults.

To encode `UIImage` use this:

```
let image = UIImage()
let data = image.pngData()
let imageBase64String = data?.base64EncodedString()
UserDefaults.standard.set(imageBase64String, forKey: "encodedImage")
```

And for decoding and retrieving `UIImage` use this:

```
if let imageBase64String = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "encodedImage"),
    let url = URL(string: String(format:"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@",imageBase64String))
{
    do
    {
        let data =  try Data(contentsOf: url) 
        let image = UIImage(data: data)
    }
    catch let error
    {
        print("Error decoding image")    
    }
}
```

If you really need to save the PNG, JPEG images locally, use CoreData to store them on the device.

Comment: Do not store images in UserDefaults. That's not what it is for.

Comment: And why is it better to store the larger base64 string than the raw image data?

Comment: base64 string is not larger than raw image data files. I know that UserDefaults are not for saving images, I just posted a solution for it and said that it's better to store them using CoreData. Read my answer.

Answer (score -3):

You can use `UserDefaults` to save your image

> Save

```
if let image = eventsFirstButton.imageView?.image {
            let imageData = image.pngData()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(imageData, forKey: "imageData")
        }
```

> Retrieve

```
if let imageData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "imageData") {
            print("IMG data: ", imageData)
            // your code here
        }
```

Comment: Do not store images in UserDefaults. That's not what it is for.